# Array in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a string array data[].I need to bind this string array as datasource in gridview.
I have values in data array.
I write the code
     gridview_forecast.DataSource = data;
     gridview_forecast.DataBind();
I got an **error** as "A data item was not found in the container. The container must either implement IDataItemContainer, or have a property named DataItem."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly assign an array to `GridView DataSource` when `GridView.AutoGenerateColumns` is False. One way to do this convert your array to `ArrayList` or `DataTable`,
then assign it to `GridView DataSource`.

For an example [click here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/binding-arrays-to-gridview-in-asp.net.aspx)